# Sort Array of Objects with same date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime

I am using a usort function to sort an array of objects by their date attribute. These objects are events and the array can store lots of events that happen on the same day. I append an incremental second to each new event's date by looking at the size of the array so each new event is unique and should be last in last out. However the sort is not doing that.

```
public function addEvent($event)
{
    //modify event by adding a second based on the size of events array
    $event->getDate()->modify("+" . sizeof($this->getEvents()) . " second");
    //add new event to events array
    $this->events[] = $event;
    //begin sort 
    $events = $this->getEvents();
    usort($events, array($this, 'date_compare'));
    //store new sorted events array
    $this->setEvents($events);
}

function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    return (strtotime($a->getDate()->format('Y-m-d')) < strtotime($b->getDate()->format('Y-m-d')))? -1 : 1;
}
```

This is all part of a ajax form that creates a new event on the fly and returns a rendered output of events.

Comment: Where are your arrays?

Comment: Your `date_compare` function is attempting to compare dates that don't have seconds. Ever heard of [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)?

Comment: The array of events is stored in another parent object attribute that is stored in the session. So for example a conference room object has a list of events/meetings.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the getDate() format to include the time and that seems to have done the trick.

```
return (strtotime($a->getDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) < strtotime($b->getDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))) ? -1 : 1;
```